# Proxy Websocket on HTTPS from the root - HAProxy

Tags: websocket, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have an aws `ELB`, behind the ELB I have a HAProxy.

Here is the proxy config file.

`cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`

```
frontend http-traffic
        bind *:80
    acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
        redirect scheme https if is_websocket
        use_backend websocket if is_websocket
        default_backend tomcat

frontend https-traffic
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/gayan.pem
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
        use_backend websocket if is_websocket
        default_backend tomcat

backend tomcat
        reqirep ^([^\ :]*)\ /(.*)       \1\ /ImageServlet\2
        server tc 172.20.135.97:8080

backend websocket
    reqirep ^Host:\ .* Host:\ demos.kaazing.com/echo
    server ws demos.kaazing.com:443/echo ssl verify none
```

What am I trying to do is, `wss://<ELB_A_RECORD>` and it should be proxying to `demos.kaazing.com/echo` websocket.

But I'm getting `403` error.

Am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please mention your HAProxy version (from `haproxy -v`).  Also, capture the matching line from the HAProxy logs, please.

Comment: It's `HA-Proxy version 1.6.13-1ppa1~trusty 2017/06/19` thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost certainly results in an incorrect HTTP request:

```
reqirep ^Host:\ .* Host:\ demos.kaazing.com/echo
```

The `Host` header is only the host header, not header and path.  The error message should have been `400 Bad Request` since this would have resulted in a malformed request.

Try removing that line, and adding these:

```
http-request set-header Host demos.kaazing.com
http-request set-path /echo
```